# Tool/Way to indentify dependencies between a C-File and a included Header-File

Tags: c++, c, include, dependencies

I am working on a project (with alot of legacy code), which I have to analyze. I divided the source-files into modules and now I want to identify the dependencies. For some modules I want to know where exactly the interface between itself and another module is. So for example if I have

`Module_A.c` which includes `Module_B.h` I would ilke to know, which variables or functions `Module_A` is using (from `Module_B`). 
So is there a way (or a tool), which is capable of telling me which functions from `Module_B` are called in `Module_A` (and/or which variables are referenced).

Note: I do not want some kind of "over-all" callgraph or a list with all references - I want only explicitly the references between two specific modules!

Answer (score 0):

You can use tool "Source Insight" for this task. It can provide you call map, reference and much more.